# Python: How to get absolute path of file in imported module

Tags: python

I have imported a module as:

```
from source.x.ReviseOnOrder import reviseOnX, x
```

The method `reviseOnX` runs another python script, say `y.py` which is in the same location i.e `/source/x`. So, when executing `reviseOnX`, I'd like to know the full path so that I can pass the correct path to subprocess that calls `y.py`.

Based on other SO questions, I tried the following:

```
print os.path(source.x.ReviseOnOrder.__file__)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'source' is not defined
```

How can I find the correct path?

Comment: You need to `import source`

Comment: @PeterWood: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: @nish: you mean the `os.path()` call? That's not valid, as `os.path` is a module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have references to objects imported from the module, you don't have the module object itself.

Use the [`inspect.getmodule()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule) to get the module object again:

```
import inspect

mod = inspect.getmodule(reviseOnX)
print os.path.abspath(mod.__file__)
```

Note that I am using `os.path.abspath()`, **not** `os.path()`. The latter would try to call the module.

Comment: I am getting : `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: @nish: where is any module being called in my answer? What *line* throws that exception for you?

Comment: print os.path(mod.__file__). This line is throwing the error

Comment: Right, but that's because `os.path` is a module.